# Drag/Drop Ranking of Portfolio Items

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I am trying to implement a `rallygrid` which utilizes the built in ranking system provided by Rally. I have run into several issues getting this to work:

- The drag/drop functionality doesn't seem to work at all in the production Rally environment, while the `App-debug.html` version *does* allow me to change the rank of the items.
- Neither version gives me any formatting on the drag/drop column like you would see on the track tab (the six dots). This makes it very hard to tell that the ranking of the grid is even adjustable.
- If I disable selection, the ranking no longer works. I believe this most likely has to do with using the selected record to save the new rank, but it would be nice if I could at least make it not apparent that the record was selected. Other than modifying the CSS, I'm not sure there is a way around that.

For context, I am using App SDK RC2, and my grid configuration looks like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
    enableRanking: true,
    columnCfgs: [{
        dataIndex: 'DragAndDropRank',
        maxWidth: 50
    },{
        dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
        maxWidth: 50
    },{
        dataIndex: 'Name',
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 160
    },{
        dataIndex: 'PlannedStartDate',
        maxWidth: 90,
        align: 'center'
    },{
        dataIndex: 'PlannedEndDate',
        maxWidth: 90,
        align: 'center'
    },{
        dataIndex: 'ActualStartDate',
        maxWidth: 90,
        align: 'center'
    },{
        dataIndex: 'ActualEndDate',
        maxWidth: 90,
        align: 'center'
    },{
        dataIndex: 'PercentDoneByStoryCount',
        maxWidth: 90,
        align: 'center'
    },{
        dataIndex: 'PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate',
        maxWidth: 90,
        align: 'center'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this app inside Rally, in prod. When I click on Rank column header the six-dot drag-n-drop icons appear. The grid should be sorted by Rank in order for those icons to show.

[image]

Here is the deployment html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>features grid</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc2/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',
            launch: function() {
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    model: 'PortfolioItem/Feature',
                    enableRanking: true,
                    columnCfgs: [{
                        dataIndex: 'DragAndDropRank',
                        maxWidth: 50
                    },{
                        dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                        maxWidth: 50
                    },{
                        dataIndex: 'Name',
                        flex: 1,
                        minWidth: 160
                    }]
                });
               }
            });
            Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                name:"features grid",
                parentRepos:""
            });

        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .app {
     /* Add app styles here */
}
    </style>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

But there is a difference between the prod and debug. I noticed that while it is possible to drag-n-drop the artifacts in debug version, the six-dot icons do not appear even when the grid is being sorted by Rank. In prod, inside Rally, it is is possible to drag-n-drop the artifacts as long as the grid is sorted by Rank - at that point the six-dot icons appear.

Comment: Perfect, I found out what I was doing wrong... In the storeConfig, I had two sorters applied to the grid. One for rank (first priority) and one for Planned End Date. By having two sort properties, it was screwing up the grid in the production environment. All is well now. Thanks Nick!